# Convertir datos de textview a BARCODE

Tags: android, kotlin, zxing

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo en Kotlin para mostrar informacion obtenida mediante retrofit y uno de los datos obtenido es `po_task_id` mostrado en el textview `txtpo` al convertir el textview no me convierte el dato obtenido con retrofit lo que me convierte es el texto por default del textview en este caso es `PO` de que manera puedo corregir esto.

`MainActivity`

```
 binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            val selectedOption = binding.radioGroup?.checkedRadioButtonId

            if(selectedOption != -1) {

                val radbutton = findViewById<View>(selectedOption!!) as RadioButton

                questionsList.let {

                    if (i < it?.size!!) {

                        totalQuestions = it.size

                        binding.txtpo?.text = "PO: " + questionsList!![i].po_task_id

                }
            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Please select one option",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        })

        try {

            var barcodeEncoder: BarcodeEncoder = BarcodeEncoder()
            var bitmap: Bitmap = barcodeEncoder.encodeBitmap(
                binding.txtpo.text.toString(), BarcodeFormat.CODE_39,
                2450,
                450
            )

            binding.ivCodigoQR.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Estoy utlizando la libreria `zxing` para la conversion todo funciona al mostrar el codigo de barras pero en ves de mostrarme el codigo solo me muestra `PO`, lo que deberia mostrar es el codigo `10866207`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]